# Aggregating data in a csv

Tags: bash, awk

I have to generate a HTML file to show how I have aggregated data in a csv file.

The structure of this file is as follows:

```
num_expediente;fecha;hora;localizacion;numero;cod_distrito;distrito;tipo_accidente;estado_meteorológico;tipo_vehiculo;tipo_persona;rango_edad;sexo;cod_lesividad;lesividad;coordenada_x_utm;coordenada_y_utm;positiva_alcohol;coste;positiva_droga
2022S000001;Enero;Noche;AVENIDA ALBUFERA;19;13;13_PUENTE DE VALLECAS;Choque;Despejado;Vehículo ligero;Conductor;<30;Mujer;0;Sin asistencia;443359,226;4472082,272;0;0;0
2022S000002;Enero;Noche;PLAZA CANOVAS DEL CASTILLO;2;3;3_RETIRO;Choque;Desconocido;Motocicleta;Conductor;31_60;Hombre;0;Sin asistencia;441155,351;4474129,588;1;0;0
2022S000003;Enero;Noche;CALLE SAN BERNARDO;53;1;1_CENTRO;Atropello;Despejado;Motocicleta;Conductor;Desconocido;Desconocido;0;Sin asistencia;439995,351;4475212,523;0;0;0
2022S000004;Enero;Noche;CALLE ALCALA;728;20;20_SAN BLAS-CANILLEJAS;Choque;Despejado;Vehículo ligero;Conductor;31_60;Hombre;2;Leve;449693,925;4477837,552;0;200;0
2022S000004;Enero;Noche;CALLE ALCALA;728;20;20_SAN BLAS-CANILLEJAS;Choque;Despejado;Vehículo ligero;Pasajero;31_60;Mujer;3;Grave;449693,925;4477837,552;0;3000;0
```

*num_expediente* is the id of the accident
*fecha* is the month of the accident
*sexo* is the gender of the person implied in the accident
*coste* is the cost of the accident for the person implied

I would like to create a table showing the accumulated cost per month and gender. I use this script:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {FS=OFS=";"}
function loop(array, name, i) {
    for (i in array) {
        if (isarray(array[i]))
            loop(array[i], (name "[" i "]"))
        else
            printf("%s[%s] = %s\n",name, i, arr[i])
        }
}
NR!=1{
    array[$2][$13]+=$19
}
END {loop(array, "")
}
```

But the output is not aggregating the cost:

```
[Enero][Hombre] = 
[Enero][Desconocido] = 
[Enero][Mujer] = 
[Febrero][Hombre] = 
[Febrero][Mujer] = 
[Febrero][Desconocido] = 
[Marzo][Hombre] = 
[Marzo][Desconocido] = 
[Marzo][Mujer] =
```

I dont know why this is not working.
I dont have idea how to generate the html out of this output. Could you help with that too?

Comment: Should `arr[i]` be `array[i]` ?

Comment: please update the question with sample inputs (5-10 lines should be sufficient) that cover a couple months and genders, the (wrong) output generated by your script (corresponding to the provided input) and the (correct) expected output (again, corresponding to the sample input); right now the (wrong) output generated by your code does not correspond with the provided input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments OP has a typo in the `printf` where `arr[i]` should be `array[i]`; while this should address OP's current issue I'm not sure I understand the use of a recursive function call unless OP's real world problem is dealing with arrays of varying dimensions.

Since we're dealing with an array of known dimension (ie, 2) one simpliified `awk` idea:

```
awk -F';' '
NR>1 { array[$2][$13]+=$19 }
END  { for (month in array)
           for (gender in array[month])
               printf "[%s][%s] = %s\n", month, gender, array[month][gender]
     }
' raw.csv
```

For the provided input this generates:

```
[Enero][Hombre] = 200
[Enero][Desconocido] = 0
[Enero][Mujer] = 3000
```

**NOTES:**

- this solution does not address any sorting requirements OP may have for the output
- for an additional sorting requirement I'd suggest OP first address the current issue and once solved then attempt to apply the additional sorting requirement and ...
- if having problems with sorting then ask a new question (making sure to include a complete list of months and genders and the desired sort order for both components)